# How to detect CAKeyframeAnimation's value changed response when it's frame animation play to end or begin?

Tags: ios, calayer, caanimation, cakeyframeanimation

I create CAKeyFrameAnimation

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];
CGRect rt1 = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, self.height);
CGRect rt2 = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.width, self.height);
CGRect rt3 = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.width/3, self.height);
CGRect rt4 = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.width, self.height);

animation.values = @[[NSValue valueWithCGRect:rt1],
                     [NSValue valueWithCGRect:rt2],
                     [NSValue valueWithCGRect:rt3],
                     [NSValue valueWithCGRect:rt4]];
animation.keyTimes = @[@(0.0),
                       @(BaseTime/totalTime),
                       @((BaseTime + 0.1)/totalTime),
                       @((3*BaseTime + 0.1)/totalTime),
                       @(1.0)];
animation.repeatCount = 1;
animation.autoreverses = NO;
animation.duration = totalTime;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

[_progressLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"ProgressAnimation"];
```

How can I get callback when one of the bounds frame animation goes to end or the next frame animation begin to play ?
I need to detect the bounds width changed,Is any way to response it ?

Comment: The presentation layer (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410744-presentationlayer?language=objc) contains the actual values of a layer during animation. You can try to observe its properties.

Comment: Are you trying to find out when the animation starts and stops? Or when it reaches each of the `keyTimes`? Or are you looking for a callback on each frame of the animation (not the location and size of the layer)?

Comment: As a complete aside that has nothing to do with your question: I'd recommend that you_ avoid_ using `removedOnCompletion = NO` with `fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards`. I'm assuming that you are using it to make the animation "stick". However, it's only a visual adjustment and doing so will persist the difference between the property value and how the layer appears on screen, which can lead to subtle and hard to detect bug in the long run. The best practice is almost always to update the property to its final value when adding the animation and letting the animation be removed when it's finished.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist   Thankyou, David ，I get  your means，this code is just one of test options to implement the “ShootProgressView”. as this keyframe block issue, I began to find other way to implement the Progressview（like  draw rect with cadisplaylink?）which need support CameraShootProgress， jump(fast forward/backward) to specific key time and add/delete previous video clip.

Comment: @macmoonshine  I don't wanna KVO the presentation layer as the following answer from DavidRönnqvist , If can not detect the keyframe value changed，I need to find other way to implement “ShootProgressView”

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Do you think it's even possible to know when a keyTime has been reached?